# YII link with img

Tags: php, yii

i need to generate code like this

```
  <a href="pic/pic1.jpg">
    <img src="pic/pic1-thumb.jpg" height="113px" width="150px" alt=""/>
    </a>
```

User can download picture and i resive picture name in msql

My controller

```
 $videos = Document::model()->findAll();
        $items = array(); // here i resive all image name in array [0]=>img_name_1; [1]=>img_name_2    
        foreach ($videos as $video){
            $item = $video->doc_file;
            array_push($items,$item);
        }   
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Document');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'itemsm'=>$itemsm,
            'items'=>$items,
        ));
```

I need to paste all my names from array to it self link and img tag

```
<a href="img_name_1">
    <img src="img_name_1" height="113px" width="150px" alt=""/>
    </a>

<a href="img_name_2">
    <img src="img_name_2" height="113px" width="150px" alt=""/>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  foreach($items as $item){
    echo CHtml::link(
      CHtml::image(
        "pics/".$item,
        "alt emssage",
        array(
          'height'=>'113',
          'width'=>'150'
        )),
      $item);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

first in your controller change this

```
$this->render('index',array(

            'items'=>$items,
        ));
```

and then in your index.php view file do something like this

```
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
<?php echo CHtml::openTag('a',array('href'=>$item)); ?>
<?php  echo CHtml::image($item,"picture",
       array('height'=>'113','width'=>'150')); ?>

<?php  echo CHtml::closeTag('a'); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In view file you can use this if your item array has image names ..

```
foreach($item as $item){
<a href="$item">
<img src="pic/$item" height="113px" width="150px" alt=""/>
</a>
}
```